# How is it decided if something is a 'software tool commonly used by programmers?'

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I recently had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386774/starting-windows-service-as-anything-but-administrator-gives-access-denied) closed as being 'off topic.' I was under the impression that asking why a service I'm developing refuses to start with 'access denied' was fine, because the service control manager falls under 'software tools commonly used by programmers.'

If this isn't the case, how can I tell whether questions involving a tool are more appropriate for a different stack exchange? Is there some sort of definition of what constitutes a 'software tool commonly used by programmers?'

Comment: On that question, were you installing a service that you wrote yourself? Or was it a service that came with Windows or another software package?

Comment: An IDE, a profiler, a texteditor are all fine. The servicecontrol dialog from windows is not something you use as a tool to build/create software. That is more on the operations side of software. It could be asked on SU and if related to server software on SF.

Comment: I'm installing a service I wrote myself; both the installer and service are mine.

Comment: I'd think the topic of deploying the software you wrote should be fair game for SO.

Comment: If you wrote the service yourself, it's probably a good idea to include that in your question.

Comment: There's not really that discrete of a line, but the further you get from the actually creation of software and the closer you get into the deployment and/or use of software, the more likely that it belongs on either superUser or serverFault.

Comment: It doesn't really matter who wrote it, it appears you're asking about the nature and behavior of services on a windows box.  That's a SuperUser question.  Of course, I TL;DR'd that question, so you might have some development-specific questions in there.

Answer (score 5):

To my mind, the deployment, and even the *operation* of the software we create is part of our role as developers. We should be able to discuss that on Stack Overflow.

1. If I'm writing Windows Forms applications, then the creation of both Click Once and MSI installers should be on-topic. Use of Group Policy to force installation of the application on a set of computers would be off-topic in my opinion.
2. If I'm writing a Windows Service, then installing it (setting the registry entries) and getting it started should certainly be on-topic, as should dealing with the event logs created by and/or used by the service.
3. If I'm writing ASP.NET applications and web services, then deploying to a web server, initial configuration of IIS and dealing with any logging issues should be on-topic.

In general, anything I need to do in order to hand my code over to "operations" should be on topic. Similarly, anything I need to do to deal with bug reports and operational failures should be on-topic.

I'm a *developer*, and this is my *job*. Anything I need in order to do my job should be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "My computer doesn't turn on and I need it for my job!" "My client doesn't tell me all the requirements and I need them for my job!" "I can't do a remote desktop connection to the test server and I need it for my job!" You have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: Nonsense. Some things are _part_ of my job. These are things that I, personally, need to do, just as I, personally need to write code.

Comment: What's part of your job may not be part of my job, or anyone else's. Just because it's something *you* need because it's part of your job doesn't mean that it should automatically be a part of StackOverflow. Otherwise, what's the point of ServerFault, Super User, Programmers, etc?

Comment: It's a different job. As developers, we need to interact with the Operations type people. That interaction should be on topic for Stack Overflow. Those things that are typically done entirely by Operations people are on topic for the other two sites.

Comment: How I, as a developer, decide on IIS settings and how I arrange to pass those to Operations are a "Developer" task, and on topic for Stack Overflow. How Operations handles IIS is a Server Fault thing. How I create the Registry entries that my application requires is [so]; how Desktop Support deploys that to workstations is [su].

Comment: It's just too bad that there are other people in this community, and that you don't make all the rules.

Comment: @bjb568: yes, it's terrible that I get to make all the rules.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I would think Desktop Support's role is still [sf].  [su] is more for the users' questions about the software.

Comment: Perhaps with some nuance here or there, I mostly agree with this. The real key, in my mind, is this: Do you think that Developers are the best people to answer the question? Often, that's the case with deployment issues. Administrators will often be good people to ask about that, too; if the issue is more geared toward them. And @bjb568; I think you could have been a tiny bit more polite. *Finally*, I leave this comment with complete ignorance of what was in the linked question.

Comment: I would consider “Use of Group Policy to force installation of the application” to be on topic, to the extent that a programmer  would be expected to be able to explain it to a customer that thinks windows app are need to be installed by each user themselves.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter.  In fact, the set of questions which would be on-topic would not change in the slightest if that wording were removed from the FAQ.

You see, the full context is:

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Let's distribute...

1. a specific programming problem that is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
2. a software algorithm, that is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
3. software tools commonly used by programmers that is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

#1 is quite redundant.  If we take out the duplication of "is a problem == is a problem" and "programming == software development" (more or less) and "specific == practical, answerable" we get

1. a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

and this completely includes points #2 and #3.

So, in a nutshell, that's the scope of the site (with the usual exclusions concerning spam, off-site recommendations, and list questions)

---

The specific application to your question is that your issue is not only not unique to software development, it is almost universally considered within the realm of administration.

---

Some further examples:

- Changing the color of a general purpose text editor is not specific to swdev.
- Configuring a general purpose text editor's external tools feature to launch a compiler passing the current file's name, is unique.
- Configuring a text editor's ctags integration is unique to swdev

Comment: This is the same as [I said before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288516/is-a-question-about-the-right-algorithm-on-topic-on-so/288519#comment168142_288519), just parse it *The Developer Way*.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, the awareness of the intersection operator in the wording of this FAQ item has soared recently.  Someone brought it to my attention a couple weeks before the comment you linked.