# Is a question about the right algorithm on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190697/algorithm-to-draw-maximum-triangles-in-a-planar-graph) led me to ask this Meta question.

When I started to flag it as off-topic, the nearest reason was: "Blatantly Off-Topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)".

I wouldn't say it has nothing to do with programming but there is "programmers.stackexchange.com", so I thought it would be a better fit there, but wasn't sure.

So, are questions like this one "on topic" or "off topic". If they are off topic, are they suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: There might be any number of reasons why that question is off-topic, but the fact that it is about an algorithm is not one of them.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), second bullet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its subject matter is on-topic, as [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288516/is-a-question-about-the-right-algorithm-on-topic-on-so#comment168132_288516). From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (emphasis mine):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - **a software algorithm**, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So, the fact that it is about an algorithm is fine. The problem, however, lies in the presentation of the question, which goes wrong at around the second sentence:

> I need an algorithm to tell me how to draw a graph as following : The
>   graph must have the maximum number of triangle faces. Edges must not
>   cross each others (planar graph).
>
> I need to know what is the name of the graph I want to draw, Then I
>   need to know if there is a good algorithm or library to help me draw
>   that.

Applicable close reasons:

1. **too broad** – There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

   - This question is asking for an algorithm to be given without showing any effort given to solve the problem.
2. **unclear what you're asking** – Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

   - This question is a request rather than a specific problem that needs fixing.
3. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

   - The asker says that s/he "need[s] a good algorithm or library to help me draw that," which is not a specific problem, but a request for an off-site resource.

Comment: Remember the "and" operator: [1] or, a software algorithm, or [3] **and** a practical, answerable problem that is *unique* to software development

Comment: @Braiam ... and what do you mean? :)

Comment: Perfect analysis. Its not off-topic because its about algorithms, but it has a *host* of other problems.

Comment: I think the "host of other problems" got my attention, but then I thought about the programmers site and thought _maybe_  it would be better off over there. Thanks for all the input.