# Is a question on topic if a research paper includes the answer?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Roope left [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519638/improve-accuracy-of-image-processing-to-count-fungus-spores?noredirect=1#comment93949717_53519638) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53519638/1075247):

> Anybody should be able to find several papers on this following the search I suggested and then read the papers and implement what they propose.
>
> the point of this site is not to become a dictionary of every possible program ever. If a solution is available with such little research effort, it's questionable whether the question should even be asked here.

The question... *in question* ... is about improving an algorithm for finding spores in an image. It neither feels too broad, nor off topic, but I'm not clear on what an answer would entail, and if it would make it too broad. The asker has given a good chunk of code to show prior effort, and a previous asker has made simple suggestions on improving the accuracy.

This [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288519/1075247) on this question: [Is a question about the right algorithm on topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288516/is-a-question-about-the-right-algorithm-on-topic-on-stack-overflow) feels like it's saying this might be on topic, not too broad and not unclear.

Should this be left open?

Comment: If it’s available via simple googling, not deep link chasing, it would be better if the OP included that research and those findings in his Q from the get-go, mentioned his experiences with their implementations, and any limitations or problems they posed in providing a solution to his problem. In general, we very much want people to try to solve their problem for themselves before asking for help, and that always has to start with the obvious google search.

Comment: Topicness doesn't depend on supplied information other than the specific goal you want to achieve is a specific problem "unique to software development". SO exist for the part of our life that is so abstract that only happens in software development.

Comment: Note that my opinion in those comments is merely based on the ease of finding several potential solutions with literally the first google search I did while not being an expert in the subject, and not on a solution already existing somewhere else. Thus, it basically seemed to me like the person who asked the question did not do even a tiny amount of research before asking, therefore not justifying the work I would need to put into summarizing the research for him. And so I merely pointed him into the right direction without writing a full answer.

Comment: "the point of this site is not to become a dictionary of every possible program ever." Actually @Roope the site's goal is in fact to contain the solution to every programming question ever. Likewise, a solution in a *research paper* is not exactly easy to find. I would **never** look in a research paper to find the solution to a programming problem unless I were already in academia and doing *my* research on the same or similar work. It's unreasonable to expect users to search for such obscure documents (that are usually behind paywalls). That's SO's whole raison d'etre.

Comment: The title of this question seems weird to me. We already have plenty of questions that are technically answered by the docs (usually under non-obvious names, or written with the assumption you know everything already). Also, why should an answer existing matter? We don't close questions after the first valid answer is posted. (Also, I don't speak academia, so I don't find research papers very helpful to the layman)

Comment: @TylerH while I generally agree with you on the research paper point in general, my opinions are only targeted at this particular question where in a matter of seconds a normal google search revealed possible solutions. No academic attitude or experience required whatsoever, and no paywalls or anything such. On a side note, if someone seriously working on things like computer vision or machine learning algorithms or such would _never_ look in research papers, they're probably not very good. Also, I shall update my beliefs on the goal of the site, thanks.

Comment: I haven't read through the question, but would Code Review SE be a good place for this question?

Comment: @Cullub The OP's code is not working as intended so it would be [off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650/154946) on CodeReview. Better place to ask it would be https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "*Signal Processing Stack Exchange is for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing.*". I myself asked a question there and got a great answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49409/how-to-detach-overlapping-contours-but-not-to-remove-small-ones-alternative-to

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see a problem with this question.

The question seems to be well-scoped with a narrow focus, and has a complete example picture to use.  Should anyone wish to attempt a solution on their own, they're equipped with enough information as provided by the OP to do so.

They've done literally everything we've asked them to.  Moving the goalposts to say this is somehow too broad or off-topic would be disingenuous on our part.  We may not be able to answer it *ourselves*, but that's fine; we can wait for an actual expert to weigh in on it.

Comment: Potentially someone who actually expert in the field may clarify that answer would take whole book and close as too-broad... but I (without any topic-specific knowledge)  agree with this assessment - looks like all information is provided and there may be library-specific short and concrete answer.

Comment: "The question seems to be well-scoped with a narrow focus" - the question is literally "how do I make this more accurate". That is not a "narrow focus" IMO, because I can immediately think of multiple approaches to improve the result (e.g. restricting shapes/sizes of matches; using the percentage of background color in a match) and different ways to get there (more preprocessing; using different algorithms; adding a second processing stage). Giving some pointers could easily be done, but writing a comprehensive answer does seem like it could quickly become too broad.

Comment: @l4mpi: SO is littered with questions that have multiple possible answers, and many of them do have multiple, different answers. That is great! I fail to see how there being different possible answers makes a question too broad. The question doesn’t ask to list all possible ways to make the code better, it asks for *a* way to make it better.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the things I listed are ways to approach different subproblems that a good answer would combine into a solution. E.g. start by preprocessing the image, improve the processing stage, then cull / refine matches in a postprocessing stage. Re "the question asks for _a_ way", IMO that is just another sign the question is not clear/specific enough. The answer "count each match as n spores where n = match area size divided by average spore size" would also be an improvement over the current result, albeit not a very good one.

Comment: @CrisLuengo also, the question does feel a bit like "my first CV problem" with OP not demonstrating a lot of knowledge about the topic. As his problem seems like a common task in that field, I understand the user saying that OP should have done more research. And while it can certainly be possible to reword it to match SOs scope (e.g. by narrowing the question to "how can I better separate individual blobs under these conditions") I don't feel it's an especially valuable addition to the SO knowledge repository.

Comment: @l4mpi:  If the question were asking, "How do I make this more accurate" and it provided *dozens* of pictures, you'd have a point.  It's asking how to make this accurate with respect to a *single* image.  That, I feel, is narrow enough to answer.  It does sound like you have answers to the question though; it's a real pity that instead of sharing that information you elected to close the question because you felt it would spiral out of control.

Comment: @Makoto why do you think it is only for this single image? I would guess OPs task is to do this for a batch of similar images and this is an example image - which would again point to the question being too vague. Also, I have dabbled a bit in CV in python (with a different library than OP) but am by no means an expert on that topic, and would not feel qualified to write an answer which meets my personal quality standards (at least not without a lot of prior research). Giving pointers what OP is lacking is far simpler but I don't think it makes for a good answer.

Comment: @l4mpi:  The OP has posted the single image.  I'm not interested in reading their minds or trying to divine what *other* applications their code may have, and it's incredibly unfair for you to do that when closing the question because of the "what-if" case. As I said beforehand, if you're not comfortable with answering the question, you don't have to; we should have waited until an *actual* expert came along and answered it or at least weighed in.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not interested in reading OPs mind either, so they should make sure their question is clear and specific enough - and it if it is not, we should close it so that OP can improve it. But regardless of if it is for a single image or for multiple images, and even though I am not an expert in that topic, I can tell you there are multiple (combineable) methods to improve the result ranging from CV to statistics; so without a better description of the goal it feels too broad.

Comment: And I'm a bit offended that you call me "incredibly unfair", just because I think OP is better off reading through the multitude of great sources which are already available instead of waiting for somebody to come by to deliver a readymade solution to their problem. There are three comments pointing OP to further resources and I believe it would be in OPs and SOs best interest if the question would stay closed and OP would look at those resources instead.

Comment: @l4mpi: The goal is implicitly, "how do I make this code work better with this image."  You're adding variables out of *thin air* in an effort to crush what would be an otherwise objective question, which is why I consider this to be "incredibly unfair".  Lastly, [the *stated* goal of SO is](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) "to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming".  Telling them to go read something else flies in the face of that goal.

Answer (score 13):

The comments you quote seem completely off the mark to me. Suppose that we have a question whose solution happens to be included in some form in a research paper, and which is otherwise appropriate for Stack Overflow. An answer which summarises the solution, shows how it can be applied to the concrete problem in the question and provides a reference to the paper is obviously useful.

Comment: And what if that paper including the solution is trivially easy to find to anybody with basic search skills? Do we not expect research before asking?

Comment: @Roope If you truly believe it is so trivial to find, by all means downvote the question. Note, though, that sifting through academic papers isn't always as straightforward as it might feel. One has to have a little familiarity with the peculiar conventions of academic writing (not all programmers have an academic background), know the right keywords (which might be heavy on technical jargon), and possibly translate the solution (which might be presented in another language, pseudocode, math, or English) to something directly applicable to the question.

Comment: Yes I do agree. In this case it seemed to me like it took almost no effort for myself to find multiple potential solutions, so I would expect that with some effort someone with less academic experience should be able to do the same. And I am not an expert in the subject and my academic experience is limited to writing a master's thesis. But I see.

Comment: @Roope: If we close all questions as off topic because I can find the answer in the documentation, there would be very few questions left.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not to mention it is a matter of some debate whether a given question can be answered purely by the documentation or whether "some" extrapolation is required. At that point you get into an argument of 'how much extrapolation/interpretation/application is required before asking for help?'

Comment: @Roope So often I've read on the site (usually in meta): If there's no duplicate on Stack Overflow - the information is not on the site - then according to the site's premise it's better to get that information onto the site. There's no knowing if that research paper will "always" remain findable on-line.

Comment: @CindyMeister yes I think technically you're right, although papers from decades ago are still well available, but you're still correct. Nevertheless, I can easily conclude from this meta discussion that my personal opinions do not perfectly align with those of the senior community, and that's all that matters. Naturally my opinion is not the one that is important; I will update my behavior on this site accordingly.