# Unity3d questions are often closed because too broad

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I just got an example of it here:

[Enemies don't collide with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943914/enemies-dont-collide-with-each-other-unity/)

A new user asks a question about Unity (game engine).

In Unity, it is possible to interact with 3d objects by scripting (code), or directly in unity's visual editor. Many problems (especially beginners) are due to a wrong setup in the editor and have nothing to do with code.

This brings questions on Stack Overflow that have no code or very little code to show. These questions (as the one above), are often closed because too broad, with people requesting a minimal reproducible example... Which is impossible since you would need a complete unity project most of the time.  Knowing Unity, I can sometimes identify what is not properly setup and solve the questions without seeing code, meaning that the question was clear enough for someone with knowledge about the game engine.

**My question is**:

How are these users supposed to write their question, or should we redirect them elsewhere when there is no code involved, like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: This question is also getting quite broad... Writing well-scoped questions is hard.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I saw many questions on meta about the too-broad flag. I saw none about Unity questions without code. I there is, maybe you could redirect me and flag this as a duplicate

Comment: If they're not being received well here but would at gamedev.se, then it's probably best to send them there.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/how-to-support-questions-about-development-environments-that-rely-on-more-than-c (Migration declined during the MSO/MSE switch)

Comment: Since it's infeasible to provide an entire project, the MCVE can be made up of a series of steps. 1. Use V1.2.3, 2. Add object, 3. add Collider, etc. This would be more clunky, and more onerous on those trying to help, but it's still better than not having one at all?

Comment: the problem is that if we split like : setup->gamedev, code-> SO, most of beginners with Unity won't be able to tell if their problem is a setup one of code...  However as AndyJ say, they could provide a proper description of the elements involved in the problem.

Comment: Having a list of steps might get messy ... but that brings me to one of my favorite suggested features that never got anywhere: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: I would suggest that the question should be rephrased from "why is this vague problem I can't give you a repro for happening?" to "What are some common causes of this problem I'm encountering?". A broad question needs a broad answer, In my opinion closing it doesn't really help anybody.

Comment: Since when is gamedev.SE considered a no-code site?

Comment: Just be glad they're actually getting closed. Lots of questions in other tags that should be closed aren't.

Comment: In this specific case, the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52943914/1) was terrible and deservedly picked up close votes. After the initial rush of users delivered their close votes, it was then improved but unfortunately still picked up the last needed close vote. There's nothing specific to Unity about what happened here. Do you have any better examples? (for your theory that "Unity3d questions are often closed because too broad")

Comment: Hi @thirtybot, unfortunately I don't have links to provide. It is just a feeling I had after answering many unity questions. I feel like I see more too-broad-flagged questions with the Unity tag than usual. About the initial question, it is ugly, short and unformatted. But I still feel like it was answerable. The two elements that were the cause of the bug were explained. No other code or screenshot added later brought more relevant information. I feel like unformatted question should be tolerated for new users, with a comment about trying to improve next time

Comment: *Unity3d*? Isn't it just *Unity* (not to be confused with the domain `unity3d.com`)?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, the engine is called Unity (altough I think that unity3d is kind of a legacy name, kept for instance for their domain). I wrote *Unity3d* because (maybe for the same reason) that's the most used tag on SO for unity questions. see https://stackoverflow.com/tags and look for "Unity"

Comment: As someone who helps out in a community for unity beginners one of the things that seems incredibly common is, they follow some half baked tutorial and didnt understand, thought they did the same but obviously havent.  They cant articulate using words we know what the issue is, nor then read more because they have no terms to search on. And as we know its hard to do MVCE that doesnt read as war and peace or say "click here to download my project"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To quote the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

Therefore, if a question is related to programming, it is acceptable. As noted in the tour under "Don't ask about"

> Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Gamedev.SE allows many types of questions, so long as they relate to game development. From their [tour](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour), it specifically includes

> game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc) including mods

So, if a question is asking about Unity3D, it should most likely be asked on Gamedev.SE. That's where the experts are that are most likely to give the best answers. If the question is related to programming (i.e. you could remove most if not all of GUI aspects and still have the question), then Stack Overflow would also be an appropriate place.

That means some questions could be asked on either site, and that's perfectly acceptable. In these cases, wherever the OP posts their question is fine.  Perhaps they are more interested in the answer from a particular perspective.

Essentially, a question that is acceptable for Stack Overflow would deal exclusively with a specific programming issue, meaning

- Questions dealing with the GUI or how to use the application are off-topic
- Questions asking about graphic/game design are off-topic
- Having Unity-specific code in a code snippet does not make it off-topic

Take these questions for example:

1. [In Unity, why is adding a Vector2 and a Vector3 ambiguous but assigning isn't?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/98715/29228)
2. [How can I create a stretchy, breakable pizza cheese material?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/84262/29228)
3. [RTS game unit structure](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115039/29228)
4. [What's the difference between UnityEngine.Random and System.Random?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/114264/29228)

Question 1 and 4 would be acceptable on Stack Overflow while question 2 is off-topic. Question 3 is a bit of a grey area, but I would say it's off-topic since it is not a specific programming issue, it's a design question.

Comment: Quoting the tours is somewhat disingenuous, because they are intended as a overview, rather than specifying exactly what's on-topic. Your deductions from those general statements are flawed, as they don't take into account the details specified in the each site's on-topic page ([SO's on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), which describe exactly what's on topic. It's not clear to me if you're *intentionally* broadening what's on-topic on SO & arguing that what's on-topic on SO needs to be broadened to cover these questions, or if you are just being inexact wrt. what's already on-topic.

Comment: @Makyen My intention is that if the problem presented is a programming problem (i.e. you could remove the "game" aspect and it still makes sense), then SO is an appropriate place for it.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see your position on this, since you're not saying if you think these questions are off-topic on SO or not. I think I must be reading it differently than you are.

Comment: @Laurel Hopefully those edits can help clear things up.

Comment: Well, actually, if it's dealing with some GUI or how to use some application in a "[software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)", then it's on-topic for SO. In other words, if it's a question about a tool that's commonly used for programming *and* the issue they are having with it is *actually* something wrt. the tool's use for programming, *and* that way of using the tool is *only* for programming, then it's on-topic on SO. (continued)…

Comment: …(continued) If it's a tool that's (commonly) used that way by people for things that are not software development, then it's not on-topic for Stack Overflow. I'm not familiar with the tool in the question, so I can't comment on the specifics of this tool & use.

Comment: @Makyen I wouldn't consider Unity a tool commonly used by programmers, at least not like Visual Studio or Eclipse.  It would be more like Flash, where there's programming aspects of it.  So while questions about ActionScript would be acceptable on SO, questions relating to the GUI of Flash or animation principles would be off-topic.

Comment: @DavidStarkey as an user of Unity3D (but not professionally), I would say that if the question has programming in it, the the tool is sufficiently used by enough programmers to be on-topic if there are issues related to the tool itself. Example : question like "How do I create this 3D figure using Unity3D editor" is off-topic here, whereas "Why Unity doesn't show my programmatically instantiated object ?" (mcve provided) Should be on topic, IMHO.

Comment: @Pac0 You are correct that there is a bit of a grey area with programmatic questions involving the application, but those will likely need to be case-by-case instances.  Ultimately, users are more likely to get useful answers if they asked their Unity questions on gamedev.se.  The same is true for UDK, CryEngine, or GameMaker Studio.  Each of those can generate programming problems, but I don't think SO is the place to ask questions about the interfaces.  Maybe [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276671) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261541) just need more attention.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I completely agree that Gamedev.SE *should be* a much better choice of community Q&A most of the time. If there were a predefined close-reason "migrate to  gamedev.SE", I would gladly use it for questions in close queue. But I often hesitate to direct people on other sites without knowing well their own standards for on-topic questions.