# When do I use Stack Overflow vs Game Development?

Tags: discussion

Originally wanted to post this on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) but I don't have enough reputation there so here I am.

Not much to add to the title, really. Why does Stack Overflow have tags like [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) if Game Dev is meant for stuff like that? Is it supposed to be Game Dev is more general questions on developing games, while Stack Overflow gets into the actual code questions that just so happen to be for making a game?

Comment: My personal interpretation has always been that SO will be more generic whereas GD would be more technical in terms of the game development aspects - though I've never posted there.

Comment: Each site explains _what_ you can ask there: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. There is an overlap with Stack Overflow on the point "game-specific programming issues", since programming issues suites both sites. Then it is up to you where to post that. // Edit, oh that help page also mentions Stack Overflow and how to decide which site to use.

Comment: There we go! I was looking for something like that on there, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: *"Why does Stack Overflow have tags like [unity3d]"* - tags come into existence when people add them to a question. There is no more thought behind it than that really.

Comment: related : [Unity3d questions are often closed because too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375670/unity3d-questions-are-often-closed-because-too-broad)

Comment: Because the tag doesn't really need burninating, I guess?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The Help Center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Game Development says:

> General programming questions more likely belong on Stack Overflow instead of [on Game Development]. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself...
>
> > Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?
>
> If yes, then feel free to ask it [on Game Development].

It also links to [Programming Questions: Here or “Belongs on Stackoverflow”?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow), of which the top-voted answer also concludes roughly what's mentioned above.

So it's not so much a strict rule as a general guideline.

It also mentions questions relating to: (among others)

- game design
- project management
- the games industry

which would all be off topic for Stack Overflow, probably in their entirety. Although some questions relating to the above may be on topic on Software Engineering, Project Management or The Workplace (but the line between those is beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: As (almost) always, the Help Center has the answer. When a question arises, then you should turn to it.. It's like the ten commandments of Moyses, sort of ... :)